# How to set up AWS Sagemaker multi input model with TensorFlow 2 using Pipe mode (can I use a Manifest File?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I have 20,000 images in an s3 bucket, I have figured out how to use PIPE mode with sagemaker for individual images that are labeled, but I am struggling on how to implement this when I have two images that equal a class / have a label.

In the 20,000 images They combine together multiple different times to create labeled data, imagine folder name is label and inside is two images. I could copy images multiple times for each combination used, but this is inefficient storage wise and will be far more expensive to store.

My thought process was to use a manifest file, this would then enable me to A) select less than the whole dataset to test and B) both images could be selected for a label.

Looking at the AWS docs for Augmented Manifest File its seems you would be able to create something like

`{"image1-ref": "s3 url goes here", "image2-ref": "s3 url goes here", "label": "example"}`

But seems the only examples I can find show only one image ref.  I have looked for a similar question, but what I could find referenced one image.

Any help would be appreciated.